# AngularJs directives isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I have a simple app using custom directive but i`m totally lost trying to use isolate scope, please have a look and tell me what to write in order to fill the gaps.

## What is the idea of the app!

a) the app controller generates a menu_list items from a service using $http then do search and return the foundItems array using the found function (this is all done!).
b) the directive has an ordered list looping throw the found items and displaying them plus a button next to each item to remove it if needed (this is still needed).

## What am i missing:

i have three places in my directive.html where i comment saying <--  <==  What to say here  <==   <== -->

also in my index.html i have commented <-- Not sure -->
as well as in my app.js commented <-- Not sure -->

please have a look at these 5 places and tell me what to do!

**index.html :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="NarrowItDownApp">

<head>
    <title>Narrow Down Your Menu Choice</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="NarrowItDownController">
        <h1>Narrow Down Your Chinese Menu Choice</h1>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="search term" class="form-control" ng-model="searchTerm">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group narrow-button">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="found(searchTerm)">Narrow It Down For Me!</button>
        </div>
        <found-items items="found(searchTerm)"></found-items>
        <!-- Not sure -->
    </div>

    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**directive.html:**

```
<div>
    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items"><!--  <==  What to say here  <==   <== -->
            {{ item.name }}, {{ item.shortName }}, {{item.description}}
            <button ng-click="remove">Remove item</button> <!--  <==  What to say here  <==   <== -->
        </li>
    </ol>
    <div class="error" ng-if="foundItem.length">nothing found
    </div> <!--  <==  What to say here  <==   <== -->
</div>
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('NarrowItDownApp', []);

app.controller('NarrowItDownController', ['$scope', 'MenuSearchService', function($scope, MenuSearchService) {
    var $scope = $scope;
    $scope.searchTerm = 'soup';
    $scope.found = function() {
        return MenuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems($scope.searchTerm);
    }
    console.log(MenuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems($scope.searchTerm));

    $scope.remove = function(index){
        service.removeItem(index);
    }
}]);

app.service('MenuSearchService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var service = this;
    service.getMatchedMenuItems = function(searchTerm) {
        searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
        return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/menu_items.json'
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                var result = response.data.menu_items;
                console.log('Result: ' + result.length);
                var foundItems = [];
                result.forEach(function(obj) {
                    if (searchTerm != '') {
                        if ((obj.name.indexOf(searchTerm) != -1) || (obj.description.indexOf(searchTerm) != -1)) {
                            foundItems.push(obj);
                        }
                    }
                })
                console.log('Found Items: ' + foundItems.length)
                return foundItems;

            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Error from $http' + error);
            });
    }
         service.removeItem = function(index){
        service.getMatchedMenuItems(index).splice(index, 1);
    }
}]);

app.directive('foundItems', function() {
    var ddo = {
        templateUrl: 'directive.html',
        scope: {
            items: '<found' // Not sure
        }
    }
    return ddo;
});
```

Note: ill code the remove method later and update the question , but for now it is not essentail.
Thank you in advance!
Update: coded the remove method on service and controller.

Comment: There are a few things to be honest; the service needs to return an array of items, that array needs to be passed into the directive via the items attribute and then the directive template needs to iterate through the array and take action based on each item. It would be easier to demonstrate with a jsFiddle...

Comment: You have an isolate scope, so to have functionality like click events, you'll need to either have bindings for those events or handle them in a controller in your custom directive.

Comment: @Neil Hibbert I believe i`m already returning an array from the then method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you were going back and forth between a directive and a component.  Components have the one-way binding that you referenced `<`.  Your directive should look like this:

```
app.directive('foundItems', function() {
    var ddo = {
      restrict: 'E', //Since this is a directive and not a component, you need to define which type (E = Element since you're using <found-items>)
      templateUrl: 'directive.html',
      scope: {
          items: '=' // This is two-way binding which you'll need for the array
      },
      controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.remove = function (item) {
          // This can be where you make a call to your service to remove the item on the server
          var index = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
          if(index >= 0) {
            $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return ddo;
});
```

Then in your controller, I suggest you separate your search function and your results:

```
app.controller('NarrowItDownController', ['$scope', 'MenuSearchService', function($scope, MenuSearchService) {
    $scope.searchTerm = 'soup';
    // It looks like you want to use found as both the results and the search function.  Separate them.
    $scope.search = function(searchTerm) {
      console.log('Searching for ' + searchTerm);
      MenuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems(searchTerm).then(function(foundItems) {
        // The service executes asynchronously so use the then() to create a callback and store the results.
        $scope.results = foundItems;
      });
    };

    $scope.search($scope.searchTerm);
}]);
```

The markup is as follows - notice the `ng-repeat`. You assign it to a variable and use that variable inside the element.  Then the `ng-if` is your condition for when the div should show which is when you have 0 results.

```
<div>
    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">

            {{ item.name }}, {{ item.shortName }}, {{item.description}}
            <button ng-click="remove(item)">Remove item</button>

        </li>
    </ol>
    <div class="error" ng-if="items.length == 0">nothing found </div>

</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VqaYgNx56qbjAQT1Xd3m?p=preview

Comment: What a legend! Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Why is the if condition here please?     if(index >= 0) {
            $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
          }

Comment: Because when you do `indexOf` to find an item in an array, it will return an index of 0 or greater if it finds it, otherwise it'll return -1, so it could be written `if(index !== -1)`

Comment: i meant why cant i just say  $scope.items.splice(index, 1); without conditions as long as ill pass the item so it is != -1 anyway?

Comment: also please tell me why do we need to call .then again inside the controller? is it to get an array instead of a function?

Comment: The `if(index >= 0)` is what we call a "sanity check".  The item _should_ be in the array, but it's good to code defensively.  Who knows if something outside your directive modified the array before this logic executes.  The `.then()` is part of the promise api.  This took me a while to get the hang of when I started angularjs, but it's important you understand it. When you make an ajax call using $http, it executes asynchronously. The function you pass into the `.then(callback)` is a callback function executed when the ajax call completes that contains the data. You can chain promises.

Comment: When you do the `return $http({/*...*/}).then(function(response) {/*...*/               return foundItems;}, function(error) {/*...*/});` you're not returning the `foundItems`.  You're returning the result of `.then()` which is a new promise.  That new promise is a callback function that contains the `foundItems` as a parameter since that is what you returned inside the `.then(function() { /* you returned it here */})`.

Comment: When you look in the controller and see `MenuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems(searchTerm).then(function(foundItems) {});`, what you're seeing is a call to the promise that is returned from `MenuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems` which takes a callback function as a parameter and passes the returned `foundItems` into that callback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125931/discussion-between-shireef-khatab-and-zach).

Answer (score -1):

Look at documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). You need to define what type of binding your directive will use. If you passing objects to directive it's going to be `=`. So directive scope definition will be like this:

```
scope: {
  items: '='
}
```

After that, your directive scope will only have `items` defined in it not all other parent scope objects. And you can use that variable as always:

```
ng-repeat="item in items"
```

For things like remove you can implement function in your directive, but what it's going to do is out of scope of your current question. Call $http maybe?

Comment: Please consider me as a beginner here , i need those missing pieces to complete the puzzle and try to understand a live example not only documentation

Comment: As the beginner, you should read the whole documentation at least once. And try to reproduce things like they are made by framework authors there. For example, you define directive in variable that only going to be returned one line after. While documentation always show `return {}`.